# Angular2 - Importing angular modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

Modules are imported in `app.module.ts`, by adding an entry below,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DirectoryComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    LoggingService
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

but `RouterModule` is directly used in `../src/app/app.routes.ts`, as shown below,

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
export const routes:Routes = [
    /* Each route will be an object {}*/
    {path: 'directory', component: DirectoryComponent},
    {path: '',          component: HomeComponent}
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

There is no entry of `RouterModule` in `@NgModule(imports: [..])`.

---

1)
Are there different ways to import an angular module?

2)
Is import of angular module different from import of typescript module?

Comment: Do you not have the exported 'routing' constant imported into your Module?

Comment: @Joe Query edited. Am not sure, What dies it mean by *your module*? Did I create any module?

Comment: "Your module" means the `@NgModule` you declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `routes.ts` you are creating the constant called `routes`, assigning it the `RouterModule` and exporting it.

In your app, you're importing the `routes` constant, which is just a reference to the Module, just like any other:

```
@NgModule(
 .... imports: [
         routing, // here you are using the const
      ],
....
)
```

And you are assigning it on this line:

```
 export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

You could instead use the exported `routes` and use that in your app.module:

```
@NgModule(
 .... imports: [
         RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
      ],
....
```

The first is just assigning it to a variable (well const) before using it.

[Typescript modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) are different from Angular modules. Typescript modules allow you to share typescript objects between typescript files. You use them everywhere, even in non angular typescript. They're the `import { something } from 'myfile.ts'` and it gets transpiled to JavaScript ES5 require statements, and just like ES6 importing. Not many people refer to these as modules much in my experience.

[Angular modules](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) are modular chunks of angular components, services, directives and pipes etc bundled to so the compiler knows what to do with them, and you can easily compose angular apps from them. If anyone is talking about angular and modules it's likely they're talking about these because typescript modules are so fundamental - every typescript file will have multiple imports at the top.

Comment: So, can I say, `app.routes.ts` is used to import `Routermodule` and nothing more than that?

Comment: Nearly. "`app.modules.ts` imports the `RouterModule` as defined in `app.routes.ts`" would be more accurate.

Comment: Correct. So, `app.module.ts` is my initial module created with help of ANGULAR-CLI for me, where angular core's `@NgModule()` decorator is used to import other modules in my module. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. That's the root module.

Answer (score 2):

There is an entry, you just named it `routing` as a `const`.
so in your case `routing` is actually `RouterModule.forRoot(routes);` which means it's the `RouterModule.`

I think angular team explains it nicely here https://angular.io/guide/router

And there is no typescript module. Only angular module. In your case you assigned the angular module to a `const` referenced with name `routing` and you exported it.